# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: error is not a function. (In 'error({]

Tags: android, react-native, api, latitude-longitude, react-native-maps

i'm trying to get Latitude and longitude values from a GPS Module Tracker which I have made myself. I'm fetching values from it (Lat, Lng). it does give me the current location but does not move smoothly like a uber car instead it changes location at a fixed point after some time. I have used `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` to fetch updated location. Is this not the right way?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Display from './src/Display';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1323137/feeds.json?results=1')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({ data: json.feeds });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator/> : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            keyExtractor={( id, index ) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Display 
            value1 = {item.field1} 
            value2 = {item.field2}
            value3 = {item.field3}
            />                  
            }
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Display.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Animated, Text, image, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker,PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from "react-native-maps";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.State = {
            region:
            {
                latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value1),
                longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value2),
                latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0
            }
        }
    }
 
    componentDidMount() {
        
        this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
            var lat = parseFloat(position.this.props.value1)
            var long = parseFloat(position.this.props.value2)
            
            var latestRegion = {
                latitude: lat,
                longitude: long,
                latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0
            }

            this.setState({region: latestRegion})
        })
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <MapView
                    initialRegion={this.State.region}
                    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                    showsUserLocation={false}
                    showsCompass={true}
                    rotateEnabled={false}
                    showsBuildings={true}
                    showsTraffic={true}
                    showsIndoors={true}
                    style={{
                        width,
                        height,
                    }}
                >

                    <MapView.Marker

                        style={{ width: 100, height: 15 }}
                        title="Uni Bus"
                        description="Route-1"
                        resizeMode="contain"

                        image={require('D:/React Native apps/track-app/assets/Bus_image_2.png')}
                        coordinate={{
                            latitude: parseFloat(this.props.value1),
                            longitude: parseFloat(this.props.value2)
                        }}
                    />
                </MapView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        paddingTop: 25,
        padding: -15,
    },
});
```

I'm trying to do this in react native.